# Am I correctly calling the Gitlab API using ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, gitlab, gitlab-api

I am trying to use the gitlab api to update a file in a project repo. I'm trying to do this using an ajax call, but it is not working for some reason. I just want to make sure I am not doing something blatantly wrong.

Here is my code:

```
var accessToken = '**********'; 
var settings = {   async: false,   
url: 'https://gitlab.pavlovia.org/api/v4/projects/156020/repository/files/trialCount.csv', 
"method": "PUT",   "data" : {
      "branch":"master",
      "file_path":"trialCount.csv",
      "content":"trial_number\n" + String(sessionID+1),
         },   "headers": {
    "PRIVATE-TOKEN": accessToken   } }

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    window.alert("success"); });
```

When I  run the program, the window does not alert success, but no error is thrown, so I'm not exactly sure what is happening.  From my limited knowledge on the topic I think it may be a problem with the file path, because when I paste the url in chrome, it says:

{"error":"ref is missing, ref is empty"}.

Any ideas? I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the [GitLab API REST documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html), which specifies that the `ref` parameter is required. An example URL they provide:

```
https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/13083/repository/files/app%2Fmodels%2Fkey%2Erb?ref=master
```

Comment: That is for getting a file in the repository. I am trying to update the existing file, which is further down on the page. From what I understand in the documentation, updating an existing file doesn't require the ref parameter.

Comment: Hmm I see now. Weird, since it does say to have a `branch` in your data instead of a `ref` parameter. Perhaps it's because you didn't set the `Content-Type` header and it therefore doesn't read `branch` from the JSON data. Alternatively, still try adding `?ref=master`, perhaps a bug in their documentation.

Comment: I tried adding ?ref=master to the end of the url and nothing changed. I also tried adding "Content-Type" : "application/json" to the header and still nothing changed.